# What is the best architecture for Auto-Encoder for image reconstruction?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to use Convultional Auto-Encoder for its latent space (embedding layer), specifically, I want to use the embedding for K-nearest neighbor search in the latent space (similar idea to word2vec).

My input is 3x224x224 (ImageNet), I could not find any article that elaborates a specific architecture (in terms of number of filters, number of conv layers, etc.)
I tried some arbitrary architectures like:

**Encoder:**

- Conv(channels=3,filters=16,kernel=3)
- Conv(channels=16,filters=32,kernel=3)
- Conv(channels=32,filters=64,kernel=3)

**Decoder:**

- Deconv(channels=64,filters=32,kernel=3)
- Deconv(channels=32,filters=16,kernel=3)
- Deconv(channels=16,filters=3,kernel=3)

But I'd like to start my hyper-parameters search from a set up that proved itself on a similar task.
Can you refer me to a source or suggest an architecture that worked for you for this purpose?

Comment: There is none. You should always optimize your network through an "ad hoc" hyperparameter search that depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: @pcko1 disagree, in many cases, it is very helpful to use a similar problem architecture and then to make the fine-tuning. Moreover, my dataset is ImageNet which is very investigated. Last, until you didn't cover all the articles in arxiv you can't say "there is none"...

Comment: @Idanazuri: Did you find any good architecture for imagenet?

Comment: @saurabheights Yet I didn't find any benchmark for reconstruction task, so I used DDCGAN architecture for the decoder, as for the encoder I used its reflection. It yields decent results.

Comment: Thank you :). Will give it a try. If you have it open source, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about an architecture being definitively the best, but there are some best practices you can follow. Check out these papers:

- [Learning to Generate Images with Perceptual Similarity Metrics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06409)
- [Push it to the Limit: Discover Edge-Cases in Image Data with Autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.02713)
- [Walking the Tightrope: An Investigation of the Convolutional Autoencoder Bottleneck](https://openreview.net/forum?id=ryguP1BFwr)

To sum it up, residual blocks in between downsampling, SSIM as a loss function, and larger feature map sizes in the bottleneck seem to improve reconstruction quality significantly. How that translates to the latent space is not entirely clear yet.